# Selenium grid node cannot reach localhost:8080

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

I'm trying to setup selenium grid locally to run test in parralell. I'm using docker and have created a yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
        ports:
            - "6900:6900"
        depends_on:
            - hub
        environment:
            HUB_HOST: hub
    firefox1:
        image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
        ports:
            - "6901:6901"
        depends_on:
            - hub
        environment:
            HUB_HOST: hub              
    hub:
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
```

Running this I will get on my localhost:4444 the grid with multiple nodes ready to start. I have an application running on localhost:8080. The only issue is when I try to run my script and call http://localhost:8080 I will get connection refused everytime. But when I try to connect for example to google.com there is no issue, this opens correct. But trying to reach localhost:8080 is an issue. Am I missing some setup or something?

Ip config

```
indows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-6C265R4
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-7B-5F-EF-F0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch) 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B6-15-B9-EC-24-B1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1089:5386:c3cb:e61e%20(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.92.193(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 989861213
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-F0-05-14-00-E0-4C-68-18-FB
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-38-01-03
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::70a8:b19d:d679:4ebe%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 722075687
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-F0-05-14-00-E0-4C-68-18-FB
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-ProtonVPN Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-03-EE-EF-F6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9E-B6-D0-B8-F8-2B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AE-B6-D0-B8-F8-2B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9C-B6-D0-B8-F8-2B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::747e:7fc6:b909:be8%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.141.191(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 18 October 2019 09:07:01
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 18 October 2019 11:07:17
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.3
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 77379280
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-F0-05-14-00-E0-4C-68-18-FB
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9C-B6-D0-B8-F8-2C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: can you share the docker-compose.yml related to the application? Here I don't see it

Comment: There is no docker-compose file for the application. This is build on the host and is running on localhost:8080

Comment: I've removed my answer since I'm not very good at replicating issues on Docker for Windows. Sorry about that. Anyway localhost is not the correct address